# Парсер парсит только некую часть информации т.к нет прогрузки, как решить?

Tags: python, telebot, requests, bs4

Я новичок в данном деле и хотел бы спарсить информацию с сайта: https://jut.su/anime/ongoing/ , а именно мне надо спарсить `u_anime_names = soup_anime.find_all('div', class_='aaname')`, но парсинг происходит только 30 первых аниме, как продолжить парсинг и спарсить все аниме, что есть  на данной странице?

При отправке информации с парсинга в ТГ я получаю данный список:
**1. Атака титанов
2. Моя геройская академия
3. Ван Пис
4. Может, я встречу тебя в подземелье?
5. Сага о Винланде
6. Бродячие псы: Литературные гении
7. Токийские мстители
8. Для тебя, Бессмертный
9. Не издевайся, Нагаторо
10. Непризнанный школой владыка демонов!
11. Триган
12. Покемон
13. Не люблю боль, вкачаю всё в защиту
14. Синяя тюрьма
15. Добро пожаловать в ад, Ирума!
16. Ложные выводы
17. Золотое божество
18. Перерождение Дяди
19. Повесть о конце света
20. Трусливый велосипедист
21. Флотская коллекция
22. Томо - девушка!
23. Ниа: Отомата
24. Избранный богами
25. Плод эволюции
26. Ангел по соседству
27. Клуб стрельбы из лука
28. Несносные пришельцы
29. Папаши-дружбаны
30. Ледяной парень и его классная коллега** , но там больше чем 30 аниме

Comment: Например прокрутить страницу в селениуме или отлавливайте запросы.

Comment: Я это и сам понимаю, но как это реализовать?